# Condition on the length of a queryset in a template, Django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to make a condition on a query_set length in my template.
My queryset is named "favoris"
Here is what I tried:

```
    {% if favoris.count>=5 %}
     my html
    {% endif %}
```

And i get this error:

```
     TemplateSyntaxError at /mysite/myview
     Could not parse the remainder: '==5' from 'favoris.count==5'
```

Any idea on how to do that? Thank you for your help

Comment: have you tried with whitespaces between constant and operator: `favoris.count >= 5` ?

Comment: ok, posted as answer to help other users. Be free to check it as solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write whitespaces between constant and operator:

```
{% if favoris.count >= 5 %}
```